# My keyboard is no longer switching languages

Tags: keyboard, bugs

I have a weird thing in my phone, usually I used to switch languages by swiping the `space` button. But suddenly its gone. This started after I added temporary a third language, and removed it. Now my only option to change the language is going into the settings and enabling only the language I want. If more that one language is used, the last one from the list is chosen.

Is that a bug or did I mess up the settings?

I'm using Android 2.3.5, on a Galaxy S 2. And I'm using the standard Samsung keyboard that can with the device.

Comment: What keyboard are you using?

Comment: Also, what exact device do you have?

Comment: information added - if anything more is from importance, just let me know :)